# How to edit data in a binding to a custom ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, visual-studio-2015, configuration-files

I am using a custom `ConfigurationElementCollection`, which `Implements INotifyCollectionChanged`. Each of the elements that can be stored inside the collection (all of which inherit `ConfigurationElement`), also `Implements INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I have a config handler class that stores the collection in a property (`CustomCollection`), when its constructor is called. This `ConfigHandler` also `Implements INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The constructor is as follows:

```
 _config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
CustomCollection = (DirectCast(_config.GetSection("CustomCollection"), CustomConfigurationSection)).CustomCollection
```

I can bind to CustomCollection just fine:

```
 <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static l:Handlers.ConfigHandler}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomCollection}" />
```

And this displays all the elements onscreen correctly.

As soon as I try to *edit* one of the elements, however, I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.
    at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.System.ComponentModel.IEditableCollectionView.EditItem(Object item)
    at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.EditRowItem(Object rowItem)
    ...
```

How can I make this binding editable? The only way I can think to do it, is to make some more traditional classes (i.e. not configuration classes) and copy all the data into those - but that seems like a waste when I've already got all the observable properties I need set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your collection an `IEnumerable<ConfigurationElement>`? Enumerables cannot be edited in the DataGrid. Convert it to a `List<ConfigurationElement>`

`ConfigurationElementCollection` seems to be an `IEnumerable`. From msdn:

```
public abstract class ConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElement, 
    ICollection, IEnumerable
```

You should make your class a  `List`:

```
CustomCollection = (from ConfigurationElement ce in someConfigurationElementCollection select ce).ToList();
```

Comment: No, it's a class which extends `ConfigurationElementCollection` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @simonalexander2005 It seems to be IEnumerable, i edited my answer.

Comment: So based on the fact that I have to use the `ConfigurationElementCollection` class, is it a simple case of casting to a `List`, somewhere? The implementation details are hidden inside the `ConfigurationElementCollection` class, so how can I do this?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 You can make a select and convert it to a list, see sample code.

Comment: If I wanted to create a property on the class that returned the class as a list, what would I put in the "set" for the property, so the class collection will be updated when the list is?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Have you tried my suggestion to see if it works before moving on to that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried your suggestion - and because the collection being bound is now a list, it is editable - so that much is working, but the edits aren't propagated to the underlying `ConfigurationElementCollection`, hence my followup question

Comment: @simonalexander2005, the items are the same but in a different collection, i dont get how editing them isn't working. Do you have any style applied to the cells? The Datagrid is Autogenerated?

Comment: I created a property on the `ConfigurationElementCollection` and bound to it:
` Public Property ObservableCollection As List(Of T)
        Get
            Return Cast(Of T).ToList()
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of T))
            Me.BaseClear()
            NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            For Each item As T In value
                Me.BaseAdd(item)
                NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item)
            Next
        End Set
    End Property`

Comment: That seems to do the trick, although it feels a bit long-winded to have to clear and add every time the property is changed. Is there perhaps a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: OK I made the property read-only and it still worked. Thanks for all your help!!